# AudioQueue iOS ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am trying to use audio queues in Objective C `AudioToolbox/AudioQueue.h` to record and play sound in real time. I can get each to work individually, but when running both side by side I have issues.

If I start the output queue *after* the input queue, the input logic works fine and receives data from the microphone. The output logic fails on a call to `AudioQueueStart` with the `OSStatus code of 560034163 (!aqs)`. What does this mean? I could not find any documentation on the internet, which is very frustrating.

If I start the output queue *before* the input queue then the `AudioQueueStart` call succeeds on the output queue. However, the input queue behaves strangely with its callback receiving 0 data (as indicated by `AudioQueueBufferRef->mAudioDataByteSize == 0`) for all buffers. My code requeues these buffers but then never receives any further callbacks.

Why are my input and output audio queues clashing like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of playing around I have figured out (at least for my purposes) some answers.

**!aqs error**

The `!aqs` error seems to be related to threading, or may be a generic last resort error from audio queues API.

To prevent `!aqs` from occurring as described above I had to ensure that each audio queue was fully setup in a synchronised fashion. Previously I was initialising both in separate threads at *the same time*; the API does not seem to be thread safe, so initialise each in sequence.

Full initialisation must take place, for example with the output queue I perform the following steps in isolation (I don't allow more than one thread to do this at a time):

1. `AudioQueueNewOutput`
2. `AudioQueueAllocateBuffer` (for all buffers)
3. `AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer`: data must be loaded into all of the buffers; I tried to initialise to 0 bytes (mAudioDataByteSize) but this causes the command to fail. My application does not have valid data to output straight away so for now I just initialise with data to produce no noise.
4. `AudioQueuePrime`
5. `AudioQueueStart`: Note that if no buffers are queued this may not work properly (I found this to be the case).

**Input audio queue callback problems**

As described in my original question, I was seeing input audio buffers come back with no data, and then the callback never called again in certain scenarios.

I found that if I call `AudioQueueStart` on the input audio queue *before* calling `AudioQueueStart` on the output audio queue then I do not experience problems. This is apparently a requirement, calling them in the alternative order (output first) triggers the problem I describe. Which thread you call `AudioQueueStart` from does not appear to matter. The same goes for threading with regards to other steps involved in initialisation of the audio queues. And the time between calls to `AudioQueueStart` (even if e.g. 10 seconds) also has no impact.

**Summary**

The first issue is 'fair enough' I guess; but I don't see it documented anywhere which isn't great.

The second issue seems like an enormous bug which probably has and probably will cause mass confusion.

Conceptually I would have expected input and output audio queues to be disjoint and not suffer from these issues; but apparently this is not the case.